# How to combine click and hover function together

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi all i am doing an example for showing `tool tip` when `hover and click`. I found many examples but i choose the below to do

http://ara-abcarians.com/jquery/atooltip/#demos

Now my question i would like to combine both `click and hover` function together, so that when user click the `close` icon should be shown if not `hide` ..

Can any one help me

Comment: I'm sorry - I took a look at your demo and I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.  Can you clarify, please?

Comment: I would like to combine `Hover` and `click` in a single event. So that when user `hover`i would like to tooltip with out close button. If user clicks i would like to show tooltip with close button. Means i would like to do `1 and 3` together as per the individual demo in example

Comment: class="clickTip normalTip" add both class to anchor

Answer (score 3):

If i understand you correctly, you can just chain functionality on an element/selection so you can do something like

```
$('p').click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
}).hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'red');
});
```

obviously you can adapt this example to suit your needs, to avoid repition you may also consider writing a sperate function and invoking that from within the event, all you would probably have to pass to it would be `$(this)`.

**Edit:** with a bit more consideration you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qGJH4/1/)

```
var bar = $('#bar');

$('#foo').click(function() {
    bar.toggle();    
}).mouseover(function() {
    bar.show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    bar.hide();
});
```

**Edit:** A more full implementation of what I believe the OP is requesting [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qGJH4/4/)

```
var bar = $('#bar');

$('#foo').click(function() {
    $(this).unbind('mouseout');    
}).mouseover(function() {
    bar.show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    bar.hide();
});

$('#close').click(function() {
    $('#foo').bind('mouseout', function() {
        bar.hide();
    });
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: Would this be enough though? If you leave the element with your mouse even if you clicked it, the mouseout will hide the tooltip again. Both options will still show the close button, while the topic starter refers to an example that show a hover option WITHOUT the close button, and a click event WITH one. The clicked tooltip only disappears when the close button is clicked.

Comment: This was more a demonstration then an actual fully qualified implementation

Comment: A demonstration of basic event chaining?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly in the abscence of a clear description:

Both events will fire same code **and must be available at the same time.** 
The events will work against eachother so you have to add a isClicked boolean to your code.

Show the close button only in the onclick event and set isClicked to true in the same event. Hide it again in the onclick of the close button and set isClicked back to false.

Split up your hover event into it's two sub parts (mouseover and mouseout) in the mouseout event, check the isClicked variable and only hide the tooltip if it was not clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript onmouseover to detect when the mouse is over the element then display the close element. Wire the click event from the close element (that is newly displayed) to complete your click logic.

Answer (score -1):

You should do some thing like

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function() 
{      
$('#foobar9').bind('mouseover click',function(e) {        
if(e.type == 'click'){         
var close = true        
} 
else 
{        
var close = false        
}});
```

Or simple solution is

`<li><a href="#" class="normalTip clickTip exampleTip" title="Hello, I am aToolTip">Normal Tooltip</a> - This is a normal tooltip with default settings.</li>`